# Установка сервера Oracle и web-сервера Apache на одной машине

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, oracle

Разъясните, пожалуйста, можно ли разместить на одной машине (под Ubuntu Server 16.04) сервер Oracle и web-сервер Apache?
Apache через php должен иметь доступ к БД, хранящейся на Oracle, для этого нужно отдельно  устанавливать на ту же машину клиента Oracle?

P.S. пытаюсь установить Apache+php, в соответствии с  [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116474/)  инструкцией. После того как стали выпадать ошибки (`'I'm too dump to figure out were the include dir is in your instant clien install'`), задумалась, а вообще так можно делать?

Comment: Стоит ли устанавливать на одну машину, зависит от того, что они будут делать и как будут этим загружены. Клиент уже включен при установке  сервера, зачем ещё один.

Comment: Можно узнать: почему именно Oracle? Что за специфичные задачи?

Comment: База предприятия располагается на Oracle. Решили арендовать VPS и развернуть  на нем что-то вроде тестовой площадки для начала. База встала, но если подключить к ней удаленный web-сервер, ответы на запросы идут очень долго. Решили разместить их рядом и посмотреть что получится.